# Getting only english property value

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get a list countries including the english short names:

```sparql
# get a list countries with the corresponding ISO code
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?shortName (MAX(?pop) as ?population) ?coord ?isocode
WHERE 
{
  # instance of country
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.
  OPTIONAL {
     ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel filter (lang(?countryLabel) = "en").
   }
  OPTIONAL {
    # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1813
    ?country wdt:P1813 ?shortName.
  }   
  OPTIONAL { 
    # get the population
     # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1082
     ?country wdt:P1082 ?pop. 
  }
  # get the iso countryCode
  { ?country wdt:P297 ?isocode }.
  # get the coordinate
  OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P625 ?coord }.
} 
GROUP BY ?country ?countryLabel ?shortName ?population ?coord ?isocode 
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20get%20a%20list%20countries%20with%20the%20corresponding%20ISO%20code%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FshortName%20%28MAX%28%3Fpop%29%20as%20%3Fpopulation%29%20%3Fcoord%20%3Fisocode%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%23%20instance%20of%20country%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FcountryLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FProperty%3AP1813%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1813%20%3FshortName.%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20get%20the%20population%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FProperty%3AP1082%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpop.%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23%20get%20the%20iso%20countryCode%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fisocode%20%7D.%0A%20%20%23%20get%20the%20coordinate%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoord%20%7D.%0A%7D%20%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FshortName%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fcoord%20%3Fisocode%20%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel)

Unfortunately also flags and non english versions of "shortName" are returned. I tried using a subquery but that timed out. I'd like to avoid using the wikibase label service since I need to run the query on [my local wikidata copy which uses Apache Jena](http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Get_your_own_copy_of_WikiData)

**How could i get the english shortnames of countries? E.g. China for [People's republic of china](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q148) and USA  for [United States of America](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q30)?**

Comment: why can't you use a `filter (lang(?shortName) = "en")` in the `optional` pattern then? Is there something unexpected or missing then?

Comment: @UninformedUser - your hint is already very helpful. Some results will then still contain flags or be ambigous but still the result is better than my attempt.

Comment: Hm, can you point me to the still wrong results? Some do have multiple names, yes (in that case you could use aggregate function `max` or `sample`

Comment: ah, ok. `Maldives` - well, that's weird, but the flag has unfortunately an English language tag

Comment: Try this pattern instead please: `OPTIONAL {
    # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1813
    ?country p:P1813 ?shortNameStmt. # get the statement
    ?shortNameStmt ps:P1813 ?shortName filter (lang(?shortName) = "en")
                   # ignore emojis aka flags
             filter not exists {?shortNameStmt pq:P31 wd:Q28840786} 
  } ` - it will omit flags by checking for statement qualifiers of type `P31 wd:Q28840786`

Comment: could you please post your comment as a complete answer so that i can upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. we need to filter for the English short names only, i.e. we need a `filter (lang(?shortName) = "en")` clause inside the second `OPTIONAL` pattern
2. for some reason, there are some flags having an English language tag, so we have to ignore those somehow - the good thing, there is a statement qualifier that helps here: an *instance of* ([P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31)) relation to the Wikidata entity *emoji flag sequence* ([Q28840786](https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q28840786))

So, overall, we replace

```sql
OPTIONAL {
    # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1813
    ?country wdt:P1813 ?shortName.
}
```

by

```sql
OPTIONAL {
  ?country p:P1813 ?shortNameStmt. # get the short name statement
  ?shortNameStmt ps:P1813 ?shortName # the the short name value from the statement
  filter (lang(?shortName) = "en") # filter for English short names only
  filter not exists {?shortNameStmt pq:P31 wd:Q28840786} # ignore flags (aka emojis)
}
```

Still, there will be multiple entries for some countries because of multiple short names. One way to workaround this is to use some aggregate function like `sample` or `min/max` and pick just a single short name per country.

Comment: you are using prefixes that are not defined in the original query. When I tried to adapt the prefixes the query would not work on my apache jena.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788703/query-works-on-wikidata-query-service-but-not-on-apache-jena-copy