# Query works on wikidata query service but not on Apache Jena copy

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki, wikidata-query-service

The query below is the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774035/1497139) for my question [Getting only english property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773185/getting-only-english-property-value). When used on the Wikidata Query service [try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20get%20a%20list%20countries%20with%20the%20corresponding%20ISO%20code%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ps%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20pq%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fqualifier%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FshortName%20%28MAX%28%3Fpop%29%20as%20%3Fpopulation%29%20%3Fcoord%20%3Fisocode%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%23%20instance%20of%20country%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FcountryLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20p%3AP1813%20%3FshortNameStmt.%20%23%20get%20the%20short%20name%20statement%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FshortNameStmt%20ps%3AP1813%20%3FshortName%20%23%20the%20the%20short%20name%20value%20from%20the%20statement%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%20%28lang%28%3FshortName%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20%23%20filter%20for%20English%20short%20names%20only%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%3FshortNameStmt%20pq%3AP31%20wd%3AQ28840786%7D%20%23%20ignore%20flags%20%28aka%20emojis%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20get%20the%20population%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FProperty%3AP1082%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpop.%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23%20get%20the%20iso%20countryCode%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fisocode%20%7D.%0A%20%20%23%20get%20the%20coordinate%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoord%20%7D.%0A%7D%20%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FshortName%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fcoord%20%3Fisocode%20%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel) it will show shortNames for countries like Australia -> AUS and Austria -> AUT as requeted. Running the same query on [my local Wikidata copy](http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Get_your_own_copy_of_WikiData) [created a few weeks ago](http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/WikiData_Import_2020-08-15) based on Apache Jena Fuseki the shortName column stays empty (see screenshot below).

**What is the reason for the difference and how could the query be modified to also work with Apache Jena Fuseki?**

[image: Apache Jena Fuseki screenshot]

```
    # get a list countries with the corresponding ISO code
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
    PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
    PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
    PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
    PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
    PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
    SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?shortName (MAX(?pop) as ?population) ?coord ?isocode
    WHERE 
    {
      # instance of country
      ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.
      OPTIONAL {
         ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel filter (lang(?countryLabel) = "en").
       }
      OPTIONAL {
          ?country p:P1813 ?shortNameStmt. # get the short name statement
          ?shortNameStmt ps:P1813 ?shortName # the the short name value from the statement
          filter (lang(?shortName) = "en") # filter for English short names only
          filter not exists {?shortNameStmt pq:P31 wd:Q28840786} # ignore flags (aka emojis)
      }
      OPTIONAL { 
        # get the population
         # https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1082
         ?country wdt:P1082 ?pop. 
      }
      # get the iso countryCode
      { ?country wdt:P297 ?isocode }.
      # get the coordinate
      OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P625 ?coord }.
    } 
    GROUP BY ?country ?countryLabel ?shortName ?population ?coord ?isocode 
    ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

Comment: can you please run the following query to see if there are those statements `SELECT ?country ?shortNameStmt ?shortName 
    WHERE 
    {
      VALUES ?country {wd:Q40}
   
      ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.
      
      OPTIONAL {
          ?country p:P1813 ?shortNameStmt. 
          ?shortNameStmt ps:P1813 ?shortName 
          filter (lang(?shortName) = "en") 
          filter not exists {?shortNameStmt pq:P31 wd:Q28840786} 
      }
      }` - the variable `shortNameStmt` should have one binding

Answer (score 0):

@UninformedUser's test query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
SELECT ?country ?shortNameStmt ?shortName      WHERE      
{       
  VALUES ?country {wd:Q40} ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.              
  OPTIONAL {           
    ?country p:P1813 ?shortNameStmt.            
    ?shortNameStmt ps:P1813 ?shortName  filter (lang(?shortName) = "en")            
    filter not exists {?shortNameStmt pq:P31 wd:Q28840786}        
  }       
}
```

Did not give a result on the truthy-based import of wikidata while it worked on the latest-all import. The same holds true for the full query. Still it would be good to know why the query does not work with the truthy dataset.